# Magento add to cart programatically based on custom price

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I try to add product in cart programmatically. I am using `KG` Based **if 0.5=>100rs and 1=>150rs** like wise it will increment based on kg.

**controller.php**

```
public function addtocartAction(){
  //* Get Product id From Form Post */
    $product_id =  1;
    $price =  10;
    $qty = 0.5;

  /* Get Product id From Form Post */
        $product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $product->load($product_id); // Product Id
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $quote->addProduct($product,$price);

        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init();
        $cart->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();

      /* Add Product in to Cart */
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart'); 
      Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your products has been Added Successfully');

}
```

It's not working how to achieve this? any suggestion please?

Comment: So, your intention is to add the product to the cart, with a different price to what is configured for product i catalog? - Your mention on custom price is not clear in your explanation.

Comment: ok in backend i set 100rs for for product price that's for 0.5kg if user will increase 1kg amout is 150rs so i need to add this price and qty? how i acive this

Comment: @ProxiBlue frontend i will take care no problems how to make work for this controller action

Comment: @Kothari instead of quantity use weight attribute

Comment: Is it possible to increment from frontend and update the price based on weight.

Comment: @Magento2 Did you get this work?

Answer (score 1):

Use this below code for custom **addtocart**

```
        $productId = 1;

        //load id in product collection to send data

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);     

        // create object of cart and initalize for add the product with its qty and save to cart and update it

        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init();
        $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
        $cart->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        if($cart->save())
            echo $sku.' added successfully<br />';
```

and merge your logic with this code.

Comment: Please Read my question I need custom price with custom QTY

Comment: You can add custom price and qty in array
see: $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));

Comment: I tried this but i cant add the custom price in array. If you know please help

Comment: @JenithSamuel Did you add the price in the array?
 like: $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty, 'price' => 10));

Comment: I tried like this $item->addProduct($product, array(''price' => 10)); but its not working

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of quantity use Weight attribute**

In the frontend, do not show price ($_product->getPrice()) but just show the real price according to weight.

Now you should use an Observer on the add to cart event to change the price to the good one.

This way, don't matter what price is set on the product because showing and adding will use the formulae.

Use **event** `sales_quote_add_item`

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_add_item>
        <observers>
            <priceupdate_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                <method>updatePrice</method>
            </priceupdate_observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_add_item>
</events>
```

In your observer :

```
public function updatePrice($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
    $weight= $quote_item->getQty();
    $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $price=$product->getPrice();
    $new_price = $price*$weight;
    $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
    $quote_item->save();
}
```

You can use quantity attribute to get weight but you have to convert that attribute in to decimal type. For that refer [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/6210/45103).

Comment: Thanks if you don't mine give me the steps how to use this

Comment: @Kothari I am not getting your price structure calculation like for 0.5kg 100 nd for 1kg 150 then for 1.5kg or 2kg ?

Comment: @Kothari `Wastage` is product attribute?

Comment: Means??????????

Comment: @Kothari in front end you are showing wastage field . From where you are getting that value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49412/discussion-between-kothari-and-gopal-patel).